# Is it possible to sort a data frame based on the text in a column which is actually an array of words?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

A column in the product data set has description about the product category where gender is mentioned as Girl/Boy/Men/ Women. Is it possible to read that text and sort the data frame based on the gender mentioned in that text?

Comment: Try using regex!

Comment: You want to use a combination of `groupby` and `sort_values`